# Multi-Select Picklist formatting - can i format just the arrows in between?

Tags: picklist, multi-select, formatting

The Multiselect Picklist gives a box for all the possible values and a box for those items chosen. In between are 2 little arrows (left and right) to add or subtract items from the list of "Chosen" items.

I would like to format the arrows separately from the boxes (because i want to change the background color (ie the little "box" the arrow sits in takes on the background color of my 2 lists and it is ugly).

Does anyone know the secret way to format the arrows? Or just the background color and width?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you talking about on a VF page? If yes, you can use CSS to style it. If on the standard page layout then not really...too much work for little benefit

Comment: Yes, visualforce page. i'm sure there is an easy way to style it but i need some element that separates the arrow's styling from the boxes.

Comment: Use the browser page inspector to find out the classes / id's of those two elements and you should be able to use css to alter them

Comment: i have not been able to understand how to do this...still a newbie at web development.